# How to recycle / reuse list of children views without having to make it recalculate size for better performance? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a Stacklayout that has list support. I load the data for this list on another thread, then add it to this view on the main thread. This works fine functionality wise, but I am having a slight delay / performance issue when the items are being loaded to the control. So after the call to the API has been made, and the assignment to the main thread is happening. I load around 5 items to ensure that i do not crowd it since it contains images (that are small in size + i use FFImageLoading).

What i have done now is to cache all of the views and then reuse it when possible. Works fine, but does not seem to improve the performance a lot. What im thinking of is to override `LayoutChildren` because it appears that the children that is added to this stacklayout, is recalculating it's size even though I reuse the View. What might i be doing wrong?

Below is my custom control:

```
public class CustomStackLayout : StackLayout
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CustomStackLayout),
        default(DataTemplate), BindingMode.OneWay);

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemTemplate));
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomStackLayout), default(IEnumerable<object>), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: ItemsSourceChanged);

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsSource));
        }
    }

    private static void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var items = (CustomStackLayout)bindable;
        items.Children.Clear();

        if (items.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items.ItemsSource)
            {
                items.Children.Add(items.GetRowView(item));
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual View GetRowView(object item)
    {
        // See if cached
        var model = item as CustomModel;
        if (AllViews.Any(x => x.Message.ObjectID.Equals(model.ObjectID)))
        {
            return AllViews.Where(x => x.Message.ObjectID.Equals(model.ObjectID)).FirstOrDefault().View;
        }

        object viewContent;

        // Determine if this is a straight up template or using a AllViewselector
        if (ItemTemplate is DataTemplateSelector dts)
        {
            var template = dts.SelectTemplate(item, this);
            viewContent = template.CreateContent();
        }
        else
        {
            viewContent = ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
        }

        // Cache views
        this.AllViews.Add(new CachedView() { Message = msg, View = viewContent is View ? viewContent as View : ((ViewCell)viewContent).View });

        // Bind
        var rowView = viewContent is View ? viewContent as View : ((ViewCell)viewContent).View;
        rowView.BindingContext = item;

        return rowView;
    }

    public List<CachedView> AllViews = new List<CachedView>();
}

public class CachedView
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public View View { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

This is how i use it in xaml with a `DataTemplateSelector` that picks between different views depending on the data:

```
<controls:CustomStackLayout ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
     <controls:CustomStackLayout.ItemTemplate>
           <selector:MyDataTemplateSelector />
     </controls:CustomStackLayout.ItemTemplate>
 </controls:CustomStackLayout>
```

Comment: It seems that you want to use CachingStrategy like [ListView RecycleElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listviewcachingstrategy?view=xamarin-forms)?

Comment: Something like that yes, but I am not working with a listview here, i am working with a custom stacklayout. Is it possible to somehow include that functionality in a custom stacklayout / view?

Comment: For RecycleElement , it need same datatemplate, your customstacklayout return the same datatemplate?I haven't find a solution to include RecycleElement so far.

Comment: yes i have a custom datatemplate, not sure how i aconnect that to a recycleview

Comment: @DissanDo Do you have any solution to do this?

Comment: Nop never were able to fix it.